# Does recipient of monero see wallet address?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I want send some Monero coins to someone else's address. Will the the receiving wallet see my wallet address or not?

I am using full client with GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they will not see your address.

In the transaction recorded on the public blockchain, some of the inputs will reference outputs (belonging to you) of a previous transaction. Knowledge of those outputs alone will not be enough to find your public address.

Even if someone knew your wallet address, without your private view key, they will not be able to know which transactions are yours and how much monero you have.

Comment: Thanks for answer (sorry I can't vote it because no permissions yet), but when I am doing exchange XBC to XMR the exchange site knows how much monero I got, and that is potential risk, right?

Comment: No worries :) they will only know about the transactions going through them